# Rails 4 & Cocoon gem - Can't get callback to fire on deeply nested fields' class name

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, callback, cocoon-gem

I have the Cocoon gem working well for adding and removing nested fields at different depths.  I also have the `after-insert` and `after-remove` callbacks working at the first level of nesting using an id.  I can't get it to fire at the second level using the class name, which I'm using because there will be multiple sets of this nested field set.

**views/car_buyers/_form.html.haml**

```
...
#cars
  = f.simple_fields_for :cars do |c|
    = render 'car_fields', f: c
  .link-add
    = link_to_add_association '  + Add a Car', f, :cars, partial: 'car_fields'
...
```

**views/car_buyers/_car_fields.html.haml**

```
.nested-fields.car
  ...
  .upgrade-options
    = f.simple_fields_for :upgrade_options, do |uo|
      = render 'upgrade_option_fields', f: uo

    .link-add
      = link_to_add_association '  + Add an Upgrade Option', f, :upgrade_options, partial: 'upgrade_option_fields'
  ...
```

**views/car_buyers/_upgrade_option_fields.html.haml**

```
.nested-fields.upgrade-option
  = f.input :upgrade_option_type,  label:         'Upgrade Option',
                                   collection:    @upgrade_options_list,
                                   include_blank: 'Select...',
                                   input_html:   { class: 'upgrade-option-type-select input-upgrade-option' },
                                   error:         'Upgrade Option selection required.'

  = f.input :upgrade_option_value, label:         'Upgrade Option Value',
                                   collection:    @upgrade_option_values_list,
                                   include_blank: 'Select...',
                                   input_html:   { class: 'upgrade-option-value-select input-upgrade-option' },
                                   error:         'Upgrade Option Value selection required.'

  .link-remove
    = link_to_remove_association icon('remove'), f, class: 'upgrade-option-remove-link remove-link'
```

**assets/javascripts/car_buyers.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  ...

  $('#cars').on('cocoon:after-insert', function() {
    // this is working
    ...
  }).on('cocoon:after-remove', function() {
    // this is also working
    ...
  });

  ...

  $('.upgrade-options').on('cocoon:before-insert', function() {
    // this is NOT working
    ...
  });

  ...

});
```

Not using turbolinks, if that matters.  Double-checked markup to ensure id/classes are correct.  It seems there is something basic I am missing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is entirely correct.

But since this is just standard jquery, you could also add a selector to the event handler, in which you can just write it once. So something like:

```
$('#cars').on('cocoon:before-insert', '.upgrade-options', function() { ...
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I've been at this problem for awhile and of course the minute I post the question, I figured out the issue.  Since these callbacks lie within `$(document).ready(function() {})`, `#cars` will exist in the DOM, so its callbacks can be bound.  But because `.upgrade-option` is nested more deeply, within `#cars`, it does not exist in the DOM until a car has been added.

My solution was to nest the `$('.upgrade-options').on('cocoon:before-insert', function() {...})` callback within the `$('#cars').on('cocoon:after-insert', function() {...})` callback, since once a car is added, `.upgrade-option` will then exist in the DOM to bind the callback to.

**assets/javascripts/car_buyers.js - REVISED**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  ...

  $('#cars').on('cocoon:after-insert', function() {
    // this is working
    ...
    $('.upgrade-options').on('cocoon:before-insert', function() {
      // this is NOW working
      ...
    });
  }).on('cocoon:after-remove', function() {
    // this is also working
    ...
  });

  ...

});
```